# why tabs not working in bootstrap 4.0.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

using the bootstrap tabs control.  It displays correctly in bootstrap 3.3.7
https://jsfiddle.net/steve_richter/evn2ncbo/7/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but incorrectly in bootstrap 4.0.0
https://jsfiddle.net/steve_richter/evn2ncbo/1/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Why would the older version work and not the current one?

thanks,

Comment: Neither of the examples work. The links need `data-toggle=` to activate the tabs as [explained in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4, your `<a>` elements need the `nav-link` class in order for the tabs to show up correctly. Ideally your `<li>` elements should also be given the `nav-item` class. Finally, your `active` class should go on the `<a>` tag, not the `<li>` tag.

Here's a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

More examples can be found in **[the official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs)**.